# How can non sudo user shutdown using command line interface?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, sudo, shutdown

All the below command needs to be run as root:
poweroff
halt
shutdown
telinit
reboot
but still a user who is not a sudoer can shutdown by clicking on the shutdown button in GUI. What happens when we click shutdown button in GUI? How to replicate in cmd?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but it doesn't really seem to be a programming question. http://superuser.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com may be more appropriate.

Comment: Please look at this thread http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253767/why-does-reboot-and-poweroff-require-root-privileges/253978#253978 it explains what and why is happending when you run shutdown/reboot/poweroff from terminal or pseudo terminal. The GUI is allowed to shut-down or reboot through mechanism like policy-kit.

Comment: Possible duplicate for http://askubuntu.com/questions/86138/how-to-shutdown-restart-suspend-without-authentication-or-confirmation

Answer (score 0):

Sudo is just a one way for a regular user to execute commands as root. The other ways include:

- processes with SETUID/SETGID bit set, which are executed under other privileges than the original caller - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid ('sudo' executable has also this bit set)
- processes that already run under root privileges and accept external commands (via API, for example), and then call the command on behalf of the original caller (also, same thing that sudo basically does)